# Store Markdown Text as an Object

Tags: r

Is there anyway way to store markdown text as an object? For example, say I have the following markdown text, note that this exists in the text editor part, rather than inside a code chunk:

```
Total Clients:**Total Number of Clients: **`r cohort %>% distinct(CLIENT_ID) %>% nrow`

Total Female Clients:**Total Number of Clients: **`r cohort %>% filter(GEND == "F") %>% distinct(CLIENT_ID) %>% nrow`
```

As we go through the document, we use a function to create 'cohort', and drop that variable after each use, thus it is always changing. Is there any way for me to store that total clients/total female clients text as an object, i.e. `summary_text` so that I don't have to type the full thing out each time, I can just call `summary_text` and it appears? Something along the lines of

```
summary_text <- list(clients = "Total Clients:**Total Number of Clients: **`r cohort %>% distinct(CLIENT_ID) %>% nrow`",
                     clients_female = "Total Female Clients:**Total Number of Clients: **`r cohort %>% filter(GEND == 'F') %>% distinct(CLIENT_ID) %>% nrow`")
```

Comment: I think you're asking how to use variables in your text? https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/multispectral-remote-sensing-modis/add-variables-to-rmarkdown-report/

Comment: Nah, I know how to do that, I'm just wondering if there is a way to store the entire text expression